# Black screen (with mouse arrow movable) for a long time before desktop starts

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, login, .desktop

After I log in, sometimes (often) the screen goes black and the graphical mouse arrow appears, and it can be moved with the mouse, but nothing else happens for quite a long time (maybe a minute) and then the desktop will finally appear.

This is using Ubuntu 13.10
- AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor × 4
- 8 GiB ram
- GeForce GTX 550 Ti/PCIe/SSE2/3DNOW!
- 32 bit

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
The issue has been narrowed down by looking at **/var/log/lightdm** files. You will find the time at the beginning of each line in those files, so you will be able to spot the action that fails.

In x-0-greeter.log, I have something like that :

```
[+0,12s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:988: Adding/updating user user1 (<User1 Name>)
** (gnome-settings-daemon:2141): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
[+55,85s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:988: Adding/updating user user2 (<User2 Name>)
```

The user which causes the failure is a LDAP managed one, not a local one.

I am currently investigating...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   I am afraid, however, this and many other things that have been happening in Ubuntu, including the decline in support, have caused me to give up on it, so I won't be able to test you instructions.  Linux Mint, although a bit rough around the edges at times, seems to suit me better now.

Comment: Hmm im getting the black screen of limbo at startup also. However mint is just as bad at going nowhere. I am really dissolusioned at ubuntu and the latest offerings when 8, 9.1, 10.4, and 16 run like a crazy demon but the latest wont even install.